# How to Split a substract of a date in python

Tags: python, datetime

My code is the following:

```
date = datetime.datetime.now()- datetime.datetime.now()
print date
h, m , s = str(date).split(':')
```

When I print *h* the result is:

```
-1 day, 23
```

How do I get only the hour (*the 23*) from the substract using **datetime**?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do here ? Why the line `datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.datetime.now()` ?

Comment: @BcK Thanks for your answer, the real scenario brings the date from a database but the result it's the same, when I operate the hour as it brings the difference between two dates it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you subtract the current date from a past date, you would get a negative timedelta value.

You can get the seconds with `td.seconds` and corresponding hour value via just dividing by 3600.

```
from datetime import datetime
import time

date1 = datetime.now()
time.sleep(3)
date2 = datetime.now()

# timedelta object
td = date2 - date1

print(td.days, td.seconds // 3600, td.seconds)
# 0 0 3
```

Comment: Worked this way, but in the import I had to use "import datetime" instead of "from datetime import datetime". Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're not too far off but you should just ask your question as opposed to a question with a "real scenario" later as those are often two very different questions. That way you get an answer to your actual question.

All that said, rather than going through a lot of hoop-jumping with splitting the datetime object, assigning it to a variable which you then later use look for what you need in, it's better to just know what [DateTime can do](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) since that can be such a common part of your coding. You would also do well to look at [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) (which is part of datetime) and if you use pandas, timestamp.

```
from datetime import datetime
date = datetime.now()
print(date)
print(date.hour)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can get you the hour of `datetime.datetime.now()`

You could try indexing a list of a string of `datetime.datetime.now()`:

```
print(list(str(datetime.datetime.now()))[11] + list(str(datetime.datetime.now()))[12])
```

Output (in my case when tested):

```
09
```

Hope I am of help!